# Confusion regarding transition function and initial distribution (Markov chains)

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I was learning about Markov chains from my lecturer's handwritten notes, but I got stuck at "transition functions". It will be a quite a while until I get to ask the lecturer about what he meant. So it would help me a lot if someone could clarify my confusion meanwhile. I'm trying to summarize what I read:

Some systems have the property that given the present state, the past states have no influence on the future. This is called Markov property.

$$P(x_{n} = x_{n+1}|x_0=x_0,x_1=x_0,...,x_n=x_n) = P(x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|x_n=x_n)$$ for every choice of the non-negative integer $n$.

If $$P(x_{n+1} = y|x_n = x)$$ then transition probability is independent of $n$. Then it is of stationary transition probability.

A Markov Chain is a discrete parameter (time) state space stochastic process satisfying Markov property. We are interested in stationary transition probability.

Okay, so far so good. But now comes the confusing part:

> **Transition function and initial distribution:**
>
> Let $x_{n}$, $n\geq 0$ be a Markov Chain having state "sp" $F$
>
> Then the function $P(x,y)$ is defined by $P(x,y)=P(x_{1}=y|x_{0}=x)$;
>   $x,y\in F$.
>
> This is called the transition function of the chain.
>
> $$P(x,y) \geq 0 \ \forall x,y \in F$$
>
> $$\sum_{y}P(x,y) = 1 \ \forall x\in F$$
>
> Since the Markov chain has stationary probability we see that
>
> $$P(x_{n+1} = y|x_{n}=x) = P(x,y)$$
>
> $$P(x_{n+1} = y|x_0 = x_0, x_1 = x_1, ..., x_n = x) = P(x,y)$$
>
> This is a one-step transition probability.
>
> $$\pi_0(x) = P(x_0 = x)$$ (where $x\in F$)
>
> $$\pi_0(x) \geq 0$$
>
> $$\sum_{x}\pi_0(x) = 1$$

**Questions:**

1. In the first line, I'm not sure what "sp" stands for (the handwriting was not clear for that portion). Moreover, what does $F$ stand for?
2. Why is $\sum_{y}P(x,y) = 1 \ \forall \ x \in F$ ?
3. What do they mean by "stationary probability" in this context? Why is $P(x_{n+1} = y|x_{n}=x) = P(x,y)$?

Comment: 1. "state sp." probably means "state space." It is the collection of all possible states.
2. This is due to $\sum_y P(x_1=y \mid x_0=x) = 1$. (Sum of probabilities of all outcomes is $1$.)

Comment: Your statement of the Markov property is not correct. If $S$ is the state space then it is $P[X_{n+1}=x|X_{n}=x_n, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1} ,...,X_0=x_0]=P[X_{n+1}=x|X_n=x_n]$ for all $x, x_n, ..., x_0$ in $S$. There is a difference between the random $X_n$ and the constant  $x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

1. "State space $F$"
2. That's an assumption.  It's (part of) the definition of a transition kernel.
3. I don't particularly like this use of stationary, but it appears your lecturer means the chain is time homogeneous.  This simply means the transition kernel doesn't depend on time, or $\mathbb{P}\{X_{n + 1} = x \, \mid \, X_{n} = y\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_{1} = x \, \mid \, X_{0} = y\}$ independently of $n$.

Does your course have a textbook?  If not, you might consider Googling the book "Markov Chains and Mixing Times" by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer.  It (or rather the first edition) is available freely on Yuval Peres's website.  Chapter 1 is a good place to start if you're just learning Markov chains for the first time.